# NoClassDefFoundError: javax/sql/DataSource

Tags: jboss, wildfly, datasource, keycloak, redhat

Trying to run Keycloak 9 with RedHat SSO 7.4 (rh-sso-7/sso74-openshift-rhel8 image, version 7.4) and getting the following error:

```
15:40:43,022 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:143) [wildfly-controller-10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:387) [wildfly-server-10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:383) [wildfly-controller-10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [java.base:]
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: WFLYCTL0083: Failed to load module org.wildfly.extension.undertow
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.DeferredExtensionContext.load(DeferredExtensionContext.java:100) [wildfly-controller-10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_11.readServerElement(StandaloneXml_11.java:240) [wildfly-server-10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_11.readElement(StandaloneXml_11.java:140) [wildfly-server-10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:129) [wildfly-server-10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:52) [wildfly-server-10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:122) [staxmapper-1.3.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:76) [staxmapper-1.3.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:126) [wildfly-controller-10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/sql/DataSource
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [java.base:]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) [java.base:]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.DeferredExtensionContext.load(DeferredExtensionContext.java:92) [wildfly-controller-10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/sql/DataSource
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.controller.CommonUnaryRequirement.<clinit>(CommonUnaryRequirement.java:41)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.ApplicationSecurityDomainSingleSignOnDefinition$Attribute.<clinit>(ApplicationSecurityDomainSingleSignOnDefinition.java:63)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.UndertowSubsystemParser_9_0.<init>(UndertowSubsystemParser_9_0.java:357)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ExtensionRegistry$ExtensionParsingContextImpl.attemptCurrentParserInitialization(ExtensionRegistry.java:508) [wildfly-controller-10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ExtensionRegistry$ExtensionParsingContextImpl.access$200(ExtensionRegistry.java:434) [wildfly-controller-10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ExtensionRegistry.initializeParsers(ExtensionRegistry.java:249) [wildfly-controller-10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.DeferredExtensionContext.loadModule(DeferredExtensionContext.java:116) [wildfly-controller-10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.DeferredExtensionContext.access$000(DeferredExtensionContext.java:44) [wildfly-controller-10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.DeferredExtensionContext$1.call(DeferredExtensionContext.java:74) [wildfly-controller-10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.DeferredExtensionContext$1.call(DeferredExtensionContext.java:71) [wildfly-controller-10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [java.base:]
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35) [jboss-threads-2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982) [jboss-threads-2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486) [jboss-threads-2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1348) [jboss-threads-2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [java.base:]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485) [jboss-threads-2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.sql.DataSource from [Module "org.jboss.as.clustering.common" version 7.3.3.GA-redhat-00004 from local module loader @3fc79729 (finder: local module finder @34f6515b (roots: /opt/eap/modules,/opt/eap/modules/system/layers/openshift,/opt/eap/modules/system/layers/keycloak,/opt/eap/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/jbeap20306,/opt/eap/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/layer-base-jboss-eap-7.3.3.CP,/opt/eap/modules/system/layers/base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255) [jboss-modules.jar:1.10.0.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410) [jboss-modules.jar:1.10.0.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.10.0.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116) [jboss-modules.jar:1.10.0.Final-redhat-00001]
    ... 17 more
```

Please notice, that Java 11 is used.
I have also added the following param:

-Xbootclasspath/a:$JBOSS_HOME/jboss-modules.jar

Without this one, it was crashing on another error.

Comment: Please, clarify your text "Trying to run Keycloak 9 with RedHat SSO 7.4", as KeyCloak an RH SSO are the same product, first one is community and the other is enterprise supported version.

Comment: @ClaudioWeiler RedHat SSO 7.4 image contains Keycloak inside, no?

Comment: no, they are different products.